# How do I ensure that user input conforms to my custom Python TypeAlias?

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have some python code like the below. How do I properly check the input to ensure that it is of my custom typealias to comply with mypy? I currently get a "error: Incompatible types in assignment" error.

```py
from typing import TypeAlias, Literal, Union
from sys import argv

CustomType: TypeAlias = Literal['MyCustomType']
raw_input: Union[CustomType, str] = argv[1]
default_value: CustomType = 'MyCustomType'
typed_input: CustomType = raw_input if type(raw_input) == CustomType else default_value
```

Edit: In line with @Andrey's suggestion, I have now done the following:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from typing import TypeAlias, Literal, Union, get_args
from sys import argv


CustomType: TypeAlias = Literal['MyCustomType']
raw_input: Union[CustomType, str] = argv[1]
default_value: CustomType = 'MyCustomType'
typed_input: CustomType = raw_input if type(raw_input) == CustomType else default_value

parser: ArgumentParser = ArgumentParser(description="Processes your arguments")
parser.add_argument("argument", choices=get_args(CustomType))

arguments: Namespace = parser.parse_args()
my_argument: CustomType = arguments.argument # This can be typed however you want
```

Regrettably, the last line doesn't have the level of typing that I would prefer. I would prefer something like
`parser.add_argument("argument", type=CustomType, choices=get_args(CustomType))` but I do not know that it is permitted in Python. At any rate, it is certain that the values of `myargument` will be of the CustomType options. I just wish this solution was a bit more elegant. If anyone has ideas, I'm open to them.

Comment: You should probably use argparse: `parser.add_argument('raw-input', action='validate_raw_input')`, etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471636/python-argument-parsing-validation-best-practices), please.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. This did work. I'll post an update that shows an exact solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrey I have now updated the code. If you have any ideas on how to better type my code, please let me know.

Comment: @nonoman657, `typing` is for static analysis and there are no type aliases in runtime. I suggest you to define an enum `AvailableTypes(str, enum.Enum)` with properties: `my_custom_type`, `another_type`, etc. Forget about typing module for some time.